# How to make multi site with single Database?

Tags: multisite, database

I have a website with 10,000 Posts. Now I want to make more website with those posts. But requirement is:

1. When I will update any post, all website post will be updated.
2. When creating a new post, it will be published on all website.
3. Every website settings will be different like Post permalink will be different of every website.
4. Theme, Plugin will be different for every website.

So the main things that I wanted to run multiple websites with my single data, but in the different look. So It won't be a duplicate website anymore.

Now please give me solutions that how can I do this. Or what I have to do for that task.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

First off please note that although you plan to use different themes and plugins, your core content is identical, so search engines can and will figure out that all of these sites contain the same content. So if you proceed, just know that you won't be bringing in much if any organic traffic. Perhaps there is a use case for this scenario, but without knowing more, it sounds like playing with fire and likely to get you either blacklisted on Google or else just so far down in search results that you'll have to have some other reliable source of traffic.

The only way to do what you want is to write your own plugin for the main site. Whenever a post is created or updated on the main website, your code will take that same post content and create or update the same post programmatically on each subsite. The fact that your permalink settings on the subsites would differ is what would make the URLs unique, but the slugs will likely be the same across all sites.

You will need to determine all of the subsites before you start publishing, because if you publish a bunch of posts and then want to add a new subsite, you will either have to copy and paste all existing posts onto the new subsite, or update all existing posts on the main site to push content onto the new subsite.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I will change URL slug with permalinks template, As well as title and others will be changed by plugins. As well as the content structure will be changed. So I think it might be 70-80% unique website as well. BTW, is there any similar plugin out of the market? So I can customize easily with existing one.